# is it possible to bind swipe left and swipe in termux right like the extra-keys?

Tags: termux

I want to bind swipe left and swipe right to buffer switching in vim. Or if that is not possible, the volume keys. Is any of these possible or should I open a feature request?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for both (swipe and volume keys).

For now the [down volume] key is acting like [Ctrl] key.

What you could do (and I recommand you to), is to edit the ['Extra Keys Row'](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Touch_Keyboard#Extra_Keys_Row). It will allow you to set a key to any command.